# 60fps ingame vs 60fps on Youtube

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've wanted to ask this question for a while now... Why doesn't my 200fps in game with Vsync off look as smooth as 60fps on Youtube? I play CS:GO and my game doesn't look as good as Youtube. Any explanations?

Comment: what do you mean by "look as good" you can increase graphic settings if you'd like, fps just means it doesn't stutter, ie it'll look smooth and not freeze for a second and then jump forward.

Comment: Short answer: because with Vsync turned off, the game/graphics card is updating the screen as fast as possible, (literally) not waiting for your monitor to catch up, which can lead to 'tearing' or screen artifacts as the monitor starts drawing a frame that has already been replaced. Youtube at 60fps is a reasonable framerate for your monitor, thus looks smoother

Comment: to expand on Robotnik: if the video frames were captured at a higher framerate (like 120fps) and then (temporally) downsampled to 30 or 60fps, this can improve quality, provided you are using an algorithm that does not merely delete every other frame

Comment: Unless your monitor is operating on 200 hz, it cannot display those 200 frames anyway. It only creates tearing and uses more power for no actually benefit. The "you need more than 100 fps on counter-strike" is a myth that people continue to fall for because they are uninformed..

Answer (score -1):

Because your video card doesn't space those frames out in equal measures. So the resulting motion is janky.

Vsync helps somewhat, but there is much more real work to be done on the drivers by popular video accelerator makers before this improves much.